# Verifying statement in preso about performance of java 8 lambdas

Tags: java, performance, lambda

Please watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLQoLbryOIE from 34' to 40':

It basically claims that there is a significant performance difference between

```
public class _14 {
    final String pattern;

    public _14(String pattern) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    public List<String> allMatchingElements(final List<String> elements) {
        return elements.stream()
                       .filter(e -> e.contains(pattern))
                       .collect(toList());
    }
}
```

and

```
public class _14 {
    final String pattern;

    public _14(String pattern) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    public List<String> allMatchingElements(final List<String> elements) {
        final String pattern = this.pattern;
        return elements.stream()
                       .filter(e -> e.contains(pattern))
                       .collect(toList());
    }
}
```

Is it really true that there is a big performance difference between executing lambda capturing an instance that "owns" lambda (stateful according to presenter) and lambda capturing local variable (stateless according to presenter)?

Or significant difference is only between capturing (either an instance or local variable) lambda (stateful) and non-capturing lambda (stateless)? Like it was stated in this presentation (slide #32): http://www.slideshare.net/jaxlondon2012/lambda-a-peek-under-the-hood-brian-goetz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your doubts are justified.

Whether a lambda expression’s object is stateless does not depend on the question whether the target method is `static` or not. Even worse, the presenter is focusing on an unspecified, compiler-specific implementation detail.

A lambda expression capturing `this` may get compiled into an instance method or into a `static` method receiving the object as a parameter. AFAIR, earlier versions of `javac` used the latter form, so with such a compiler you wouldn’t even see such a code change presented in that video.

You can emulate such a behavior by rewriting the code to:

```
public List<String> allMatchingElements(final List<String> elements) {
    final _14 arg = this;
    return elements.stream()
                   .filter(e -> e.contains(arg.pattern))
                   .collect(toList());
}
```

Now, this lambda expression doesn’t capture `this`, but a local variable `arg` which contains the same object which is passed as first argument to a synthetic `static` method, but it should be obvious that there is no difference to a `this` capturing lambda invoking a synthetic instance method.

So the change made in that presentation will affect whether the generated instance will capture the `this` instance or the `pattern` string, which doesn’t change the capturing nature of the lambda expression and the fact that the *current JRE implementation* will create a new instance in each capturing process. But the performance impact is negligible for most use cases anyway.

The only scenario where you should avoid capturing `this` when you can, is when you assume that the lambda expression’s instance may have a longer lifetime, as having captured `this` may prevent its garbage collection.

For a temporary object like in the use case of that presentation, there is no need to worry. It could be seen as an ironic twist that with the current implementation, you will create half a dozen temporary object instances with the Stream operation shown, but the presenter focuses on that single temporary instance created for the lambda expression…